# Angular momentum conservation question

Tags: angular-momentum, conservation-laws

I have a Hamiltonian of the form

$$\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{Z^2e^2}{4\pi\epsilon R}+\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon\left|\vec{r}-\vec{R}_1\right|}+\frac{Ze^2}{4\pi\epsilon\left|\vec{r}-\vec{R}_2\right|}$$

Basically I have 2 particles of charge $Ze$ fixed in space (e.g. they have infinite mass) and a particle of mass $m$ that is free to move of charge $-e$. $R_{1,2}$ are the locations of the 2 massive particles and $r$ the location of the moving particle. Given that we have a preferential direction in space (i.e. we can define the z-axis along the line connecting the 2 massive particles), the system doesn't have cylindrical symmetry, so the angular momentum $L$ is not conserved. However, I thought that the total angular momentum of a closed system (which our system is) is always conserved. What am I doing wrong here? Why is the total angular momentum not conserved here?

Comment: If the two fixed charges  are fixed to *something*, the total angular momentum of both the movable particle and the *something* stays constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two particles fixed in space, yet you're calling it a closed system. If you choose a definition of "closed system" that applies when you have some particles fixed in space, then angular momentum is *not* always conserved in a closed system. Conversely, if you choose a definition of "closed system" so that the angular momentum of a closed system is always conserved, then a closed system can't have particles fixed in space.

FWIW, I've seen the words "closed system" used both ways. This is just one of many examples where the same words are used with different meanings in different contexts. Words are cheap, and they're frequently recycled. [Equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) is absolutely rampant in physics, just like it is in any other technical or nontechnical area.

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean. I remember when I saw the first derivation of the hydrogen atom (it was based on Griffiths book), he assumed that the nucleus is fixed and only the electron can move. Yet he obtained spherical harmonics out of that derivation and hence conserved angular momentum. Is there something special about that case comparing to this one?

Comment: @BillKet With only one fixed particle, the system still has rotational symmetry about that point, so angular momentum about that one point can still be conserved. Angular momentum about other points won't be conserved, because the fixed particle breaks rotational symmetry about all other points.